# What is the GENERIC_WRITE constant hex value in windows?

Tags: windows, assembly, 64-bit

I'm trying to open a file for writing using the CreatFileA system call in assembly in x64, however in order to do so I need to specify the desired access. I don't know what the constant is for GENERIC_WRITE, the GENERIC_READ constant is 80000000h.

```
; create the file
lea rcx, fileName
mov rdx, 40000000h
xor r8, r8
xor r9, r9
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+48h-28h], 2
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+48h-20h], 80h
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+48h-18h], 0
call CreateFileA
mov FD2, rax

; write to the new file
lea rcx, FD2
lea rdx, buffer
mov r8, len
lea r9, written
mov QWORD PTR [rsp+48h-28h], 0
call WriteFile
mov writeResult, rax
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374896(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can you explain that page further? thanks

Comment: It lays out the bits and their meaning. But consider GENERIC_READ. You know the value is the left most bit being set thus 0x80000000 . GENERIC_WRITE would be the second left most bit being set or 0x40000000

Comment: This lays out the specific values: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Remoting/channels/ipc/win32namedpipes.cs,c71d88bb8f3c473c

Comment: You could also just look in winnt.h

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but when I attempt to write to the file, I get error code 6, which is an invalid handle error, I will update my post with relevant code

Comment: The 80h is something different, it is setting the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL attribute.

Comment: Where are you getting error 6?  Are you calling GetLastError?

Comment: Yes, it is the next line in my code.

Comment: Have you examined the contents of ecx when calling WriteFile?  `lea rcx, FD2` doesn't seem right.

Comment: Ahh, you're right! The call is looking for a file handle, yet I was giving the address to the file handle. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This free online tool "magnumdb.com" (disclaimer: I'm the author) can help you with these kind of questions: https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=GENERIC_WRITE => 0x40000000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turning the comments into an answer so this can get closed out.

As Michael points out, the bits that make up the Access Mask are defined [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374896(v=vs.85).aspx).

Using that we see that GENERIC_READ is 0x80000000 and GENERIC_WRITE is 0x40000000.

Generally speaking, you should probably look at Windows' headers to get the definitive and most up-to-date values for all Windows constants.  This one is in Winnt.h.

Addressing the follow-on question, your assembler code to load the handle to be passed to WriteFile is incorrect.  You are saving the value returned from CreateFile using

```
mov FD2, rax
```

But then you load it back using

```
lea rcx, FD2
```

`lea` is going to return a pointer to the handle, not the handle itself.

So, for once, Windows was really being helpful when it returned the *The handle is invalid* error message.  (By implication) it told which parameter was the source of the problem, and (roughly) what the problem was.